# How to implement push notification in Nokia Series 40 using Nokia Java SDK 2.0?

Tags: java-me, push-notification, nokia-s40

I want my app to be able to receive notification from the server while it is running in the background. I don't like pooling, that will drain user's battery since I need almost realtime response, does Series 40 support that?

Comment: I like pooling, especially with a cocktail in my hand ;)

Comment: I do, too, when it's really really hot :)

Comment: If it was me, I'd probably use SMS. You can find webhotel providers that offers SMS service.

Comment: the problem now is that 

#1, can SMS be responsive enough on an international basis,

#2, can I intercept SMS on series 40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question if you can intercept SMS on an S40 phone then I'd say yes. You can use push registry. See this [link](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_launch_a_MIDlet_remotely_via_SMS_or_locally_via_an_Alarm_with_PushRegistry_in_Java_ME) for the j2me sample. This is only half of the problem as this is the receiving end. You need to create a server that "pushes" a message to a certain mobile number on it's push registry port. You can use an SMS gateway maybe to push messages?