# server push message in j2me app

Tags: java, java-me, push

I want to launch my j2me midlet on server push message.for that I have studied some topics ,so  I came to know I have to implement socket based push messages for my j2me app.But can't found proper resource.
pls help..

Comment: Google for JavaME PushRegistry

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617514/how-to-implement-push-notification-in-nokia-series-40-using-nokia-java-sdk-2-0/15633419#15633419). The J2ME PushRegistry side is just a piece of the puzzle. You still need a "server" that will push messages on your registered PushRegistry port.